# how to get values passed on from Custom tag in your TagHandler?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How do I get values passed as a tag attribute on a JSP page?

```
<abc:myTag name="${userName}", empId="${empId}">
  <b> Displaying user's info in HTML </b>
<abc:myTag />
```

I need to access the value of userName and empId in my TagHandler class:

```
public class myTag extends TagSupport {

       protected String name = null;
       protected String empId = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }


    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public int doStartTag() throws javax.servlet.jsp.JspException {

      //Need UserName and EmpID fields in this method.
      //How?

        return Tag.SKIP_BODY;

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for comma when tag is invoked.

```
<abc:myTag name="${userName}" empId="${empId}">   
<b> Displaying user's info in HTML </b> 
<abc:myTag />
```

Try this out.

```
public int doStartTag() throws javax.servlet.jsp.JspException {        
//Access UserName and EmpID fields in this method. 

name = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("name",PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
empId = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("empId",PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
return Tag.SKIP_BODY;         
}
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, Thanks for correcting the comma. It was a typo. Didnt try your solution but the values are implicitly available in Tag Handler as long as you define a setter for every field.